# Variance estimator using mixture of scaled and unscaled data

Tags: variance, inference, unbiased-estimator, estimators, consistency

Given two datasets:

$X_1, \dots, X_n \sim N(1, \sigma^2)$

and

$X_{n+1}, \dots, X_N \sim N(1, 2\sigma^2)$

My proposed estimator for $\sigma^2$ is simply a scaled combination of both classical estimators as follows:

$\frac{1}{3}\times \left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}-n(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}/n)^2}{n-1} + \frac{\sum_{i=n+1}^{N}x_{i}^{2}-(N-n)(\sum_{i=n+1}^{N}x_{i}/(N-n))^2}{N-n-1} \right]$

I can show that this is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$

Is this valid? i.e. can I produce an estimator simply using linear combinations of two estimators or are there issues I need to account for beyond maintaining unbiasedness, consistency, and reducing estimator variance?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "valid."

Comment: Can I produce an estimator simply using linear combinations of two estimators or are there issues I need to account for beyond maintaining unbiasedness, consistency, and reducing estimator variance?

Comment: Of course you can create an estimator that way.  Whether it is any good depends on the properties you need it to have.  Unbiasedness, consistency, and low variance are some common attractive properties, but many others are possible (and used in practical situations).  That's why you need to tell us specifically what you mean by a "valid" estimator.

Comment: Thank you. I guess my question was rather loose; my main concern was that I could be violating some property which leads to an adverse effect on consistency and/or unbiasedness by automatically combining two known estimators instead of deriving one using MLE or MoM. This is just for self-study, so I'm not looking for any particular practical use that would define what it means to be valid; I just needed a consistent unbiased estimator that uses all the data.

Comment: Since both estimators are unbiased, any linear combination will be.  You could determine the coefficients uniquely, then, by minimizing the bias.